# How to style the td in only one grid when my page have two grids?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

My page have two grids called grid1,grid2,I only want to style the grid1,not grid2.I use the css style in the header like  this,but  it seems that both grid changed.

```
.k-grid td {
   color:red;
  padding: 0px;
 }
```

I try to write like this,but failed.

```
 .GridTd {
 color:red;
 padding: 0px;
}
$("#grid1 td").addClass("GridTd "); //failed
$("#grid1 k-grid   td").addClass("GridTd ");// faied
```

I debug with firebug and find that the td style is used by default style(.k-grid td),not GridTd Style.

```
 .k-grid td {  
   border-style: solid;    border-width: 0 0 0 1px;   
  line-height: 1.6em;    overflow: hidden;    
  padding: 0.4em 0.6em;    text-overflow: ellipsis;  
  vertical-align: middle;
  }.
.GridTd {  color:red;   padding: 0;}
```

Comment: Could you please post some html or link?

Comment: I style the td with 'GridTd' ,but it still use the default style.I feel strange

Answer (score 1):

If the two rules are in the same order as per your code sample

Then this has to do with the specificity of css

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/ 
http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

One solution is to specify the css by using the `.css()` jQuery function

http://api.jquery.com/css/

Example

```
$("#grid1 td").css({  "color":"red", "padding": "0"});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I'm using the kendo MVC wrapper. Here's how I handled it:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Model>()
    .Name("MyGrid")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "k-grid-MyGrid" } )

    ...(Imagine the rest of the grid)
)
```

Then in css reference like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .k-grid-MyGrid td {
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
</style>
```

Hope that helps you.